# Camera following target in Box2D

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d

I am trying to follow player with camera in Box2D world. But there is an offset. And I think it has something to do with pixel per meter conversion. Before you check my code you should know that `Values.WTB = World_To_Box and has a values of 0.032f` and `Values.BTW = Box_To_World and has a values of 32f`.

Here is the render part:

```
@Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0.105f,0.105f,0.105f,1f);

        camera.position.set(player.getPosition().x*Values.BTW, player.getPosition().y*Values.BTW, 0);
        camera.update();

        Matrix4 cameraCopy = camera.combined.cpy();
        cameraCopy.scl(Values.BTW);
        batch.setProjectionMatrix(cameraCopy);
        shapeRenderer.setProjectionMatrix(cameraCopy);

        batch.begin();
        player.draw(batch);
        batch.end();

        debugRenderer.render(world, cameraCopy);

        world.step(1/60f, 6, 2);

        shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeType.Filled);

        shapeRenderer.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        shapeRenderer.circle(player.getPosition().x, player.getPosition().y, 5*Values.WTB,10);

        shapeRenderer.setColor(Color.ORANGE);
        shapeRenderer.circle(camera.position.x*Values.WTB, camera.position.y*Values.WTB, 5*Values.WTB,10);

        shapeRenderer.end();
    }
```

and here is picture to demonstrate:
[image]

**Green** point is where the center of player is and **Orange** point is where the camera center is. And further you go from 0,0 coordinates the bigger is offset.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why Values.WTB = World_To_Box and has a values of 0.032f ??? why not 0.32f

Comment: I used it because bigger value results in huge sizes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Values.WTB = World_To_Box and has a values of 0.032f and Values.BTW = Box_To_World and has a values of 32f

There is no reason to change your WTB / BTW values to 0.01f and 100f like it was suggested by others, since yours are *nearly* correct. Conversions in powers of two are also a lot faster than conversions by 100.

If you want 32 screen pixels per box2d meter then keep using `Values.BTW = 32f`. But then `Values.WTB` would be `1f / 32f = 0.03125f`, not `0.032f`. It is just a small difference, but it makes a difference in the end.

Comment: changing 0.032f to 0.03125f did the trick. But without cameraCopy.scl(Values.BTW); box2d world is fraction of the screen.

Comment: @RohitMalish That seems odd to me. Maybe it has something to do with how you setup your renderers' viewports. But that's not part of the code and your problem seems to be solved... so however :)

Comment: I am setting cameras position but I never scale it, until cameraCopy.scl(Values.BTW);

Comment: @RohitMalish But here `camera.position.set(player.getPosition().x*Values.BTW, player.getPosition().y*Values.BTW` you do scale it, don't you?

Comment: but does it scale it if im only setting position? im scaling player position, right?

Comment: @RohitMalish Ah, I got it now. Actually, you don't scale the player position, because you just scale the x and y values. That basically means, you scale the camera *position*. When doing `cameraCopy.scl(Values.BTW);` you scale the camera *viewport*. You probably have to do that, because your camera viewport is initially in box2d units, right? (that means you set it up with width * WTB or width / BTW)

Comment: not really, I create it with empty constructor like this camera = new OrthographicCamera();

Comment: @RohitMalish Well, in this case the screen size is used as the viewport and you shouldn't need this second scale. Well, it will remain a mystery then, at least to me. I will remove that part from my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Change your values to:

```
static final float WORLD_TO_BOX = 0.01f;
static final float BOX_TO_WORLD = 100f;
```

Why 0.032 and 32 are not working: 
For example if you want to convert 100px to Box2d units:
100 * 0.032 = 3.2
And then from Box2d units to pixels:
3.2 * 32 = 102.4

And of course the difference will be bigger if you are converting bigger values.